# MySQL - NOT IN LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like, in-operator, not-operator

How can I, in mysql, check if a value is inside a number of fields in another table?

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat('%',value,'%') NOT LIKE IN(SELECT field FROM anothertable)
```

But I don't think that's quite right, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* 
FROM   table t, 
       anothertable a 
WHERE  a.field NOT LIKE Concat('%', t.`value`, '%');
```

Comment: Would this be faster or better in some way?

Comment: Yes, if field and value are indexed it'll be much faster

Comment: I compared the two, this one is 4 times faster then the first one.

Comment: Oh wow, and after that last modification, it's nearly instant.

Answer (score 2):

No, not quite.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * from anothertable WHERE field LIKE CONCAT('%',value,'%')
)
```

will probably do it. Assuming that `value` is a column on `table`, and `field` is the corresponding column on `anothertable` which may or may not contain `value` as a substring.

Be warned, though -- this is going to be a very slow query, if `anothertable` contains many rows. I don't think there's an index that can help you. MySQL will have to to a string-comparing table scan of `anothertable` for every row in `table`.

Comment: I figured it'd be slow, but I'm just running a one-time maintenance query.

Comment: Btw, I just updated for a typo -- I had 'NOT LIKE' in place of 'LIKE' in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (assuming you wish to find the value from table in 2 fields (field1 and field2) in "anothertable"):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Count(*) FROM anothertable WHERE field1 LIKE concat('%',t,value,'%') OR field2 LIKE concat('%',t,value,'%')
```